# How to host a multi-service solution with segregated front-end

Tags: rest, docker, docker-compose, frontend, microservices

For a project, I'm building a web application that makes use of different restful components that I developed. Right now I have:

1. An API for parsing some XSD data (Java)
2. An API to connect to some remote database depending on provided
   arguments (NodeJS)
3. An API for doing some data-analytics (Rstudio/Plumber)

All of the components are RESTful. Right now I'm using the java (Spring) component (1) to host my webpage and all the front-end. I would like to have the webpage hosted separately as well and have a correct way for communicating in between components (right now I just run them all and send requests to localhost:xxxx depending on which port they're on).

Ultimately I would like to have one executable with a structure similar to the one below. Note that I would not like the API's to be accessible from outside the environment of my solution.[image]

- Is there a way to do this using Docker?
- How can I run my front-end separately without any back-end, and make it accessible from outside the environment?
- On which address can I reach the API's in my code once I get it to
  work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do it. you can containerize your api but depends how you want to run them. All the cloud services provide different options to run containers if you are considering cloud service.

**Is there a way to do this using Docker?**

you can run these apis in containers independently but Generally you have to use some kind of container orchestration service(e.g . kubernetes) to run your containers.

**On which address can I reach the API's in my code once I get it to work?**

You package all your apis including your web front end in containers and deploy to kubernetes which is cluster of nodes.  only your front end will have external ip assigned and your other apis can only be reached via front end since they are sitting behind firewall with private ip. kubernetes has its own networking inside and services (your api) within cluster can be accessed simply by service name.

another way is to deploy all the apis in virtual network and only frontend (with public ip) will have access to those services.

**How can I run my front-end separately without any back-end, and make it accessible from outside the environment?**

you can run your frontend in kubernetes as container as discussed above or you can deploy your static frontend (only htm css) to some static hosting e.g. aws s3 or azure static web sites.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!